# Setting the value fails in Java

Tags: java, sql

I am working on Java coding..
Trying to set author value:

```
XXX.setStatusValue(YYY.AUTHOR.toString());
```

When trying to insert this value in database,

Here is the error I get:

> too long for column 'status_value' at row 1

I have not designed the tables, just using the existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

> Here is the error i get: too long for column 'status_value' at row 1

The error says it all.

The value you are trying to insert into the database is larger than the maximum length allowable in the field in the table.

Either insert a shorter string, or make the field in the database longer.

Answer (score 0):

I think all database columns have it's own length and you cannot set value have bigger than that. If you don't know how long is your column length, just try insert value with increase length (example from 1 to 200). When error occurs, you will know exactly length of column.